# Tint color in Video Editing

Tags: materials

I'm learning 2D animation in Blender.

[image]

my material fill color is green

[image]

I added a Tint Modifier in Red.

[image]

When I put this shot into Video Editing, it doesn't show Tint color, only shows material color.

Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: maybe you should share your blend file. It is always easier to check this out than thinking "theoretically" over your posted settings screenshots...